# An Era of Change

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, word-property, video-games

*Despite their appearances, the following are* not *ways of change... at least, I hope not.*

> 1. Kids s*h*ows (8+?)
> 2. Liza*r*d (6+?)
> 3. Mis*s*iles group (5+?)
> 4. *B*ody manipulator (4+?)
> 5. Bi*r*d (3+?)
> 6. Emp*e*ror (5+?)

The final answer is a **thematic phrase.**

**Hint 1:** (updated)

[connections-puzzle](/questions/tagged/connections-puzzle) is now [word-property](/questions/tagged/word-property).

**Hint 2:** (updated)

[video-games](/questions/tagged/video-games) tag added.

**Hint 3:**

> ? = 3

**Hint 4:** (updated, minor spoiler?)

> "Change/ways of change" is a hint for the video game(s) being referenced; the specific kind of change is hinted by "era,” which is also the identity of the ?.

**Hint 5:** (major spoilers)

> Some actual ways of change include fire (4+?) and water (5+?), but not fish (4+? or 5+?) or reptile (4+? or 7+?).

Comment: My current working hypothesis... rot13(V'ir orra ybbxvat ng jbeqf znqr bs gur ahzore bs yrggref tvira cyhf gur 3 yrggref R, E naq N va gur 6 cbffvoyr beqref, trggvat jbeqf yvxr r.t zNffRhE, cREgvaNk.) Is this anywhere close? Also have some ideas of the step(s) to follow after that, because obviously this isn't everything...

Comment: Hm. I'm thinking more along [these lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age), but I'm not going anywhere with the other words.

Comment: @Stiv That's a great idea, but it's not on the right track. The word property tag is central to figuring out the solutions to the clues, and no permuting needs to be done i.e. "change" refers to something else. Let me know if I need to provide more hints!

Comment: Rot13(V guvax "punatr" unf gb qb jvgu pbva-bc ivqrb tnzrf.  Ohg V unir ab vqrn jung gubfr ivqrb tnzrf unir gb qb jvgu gur pyhrf.)

Comment: @JS1 That's not the reference I'm looking for either, but you are right in suspecting that rot13(punatr, be fbzrguvat fvzvyne gb vg, vf yvaxrq gb gur ivqrb tnzr(f) ersreraprq va guvf chmmyr va fbzr jnl)

Comment: (I might post that as a hint actually)

Comment: I suspect MOehm is on the right track and have a conjecture about the body manipulator, but haven't had much success looking for more...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So given all the hints, I figured out these words that fit:

Kids s*h*ows (8+?)

> Nicke**l**odeon

Liza*r*d (6+?)

> Cham**e**leon

Mis*s*iles group (5+?)

> Ray**t**heon (Thanks to Alconja)

*B*ody manipulator (4+?)

> **S**urgeon

Bi*r*d (3+?)

> Pi**g**eon

Emp*e*ror (5+?)

> Nap**o**leon

And then:

> For each answer, if you take the italicized letter in its clue, and find the letter in the answer at the same position (which I bolded above), you get the answer:
>
>  **Let's Go**
>
>  This is the name of a Pokemon video game. The "era of change" refers to the 8 "-eon" type Pokemon, which the normal type Eevee can evolve into: Jolteon (Electric), Flareon (Fire), Vaporeon (Water), Umbreon (Dark), Espeon (Psychic), Leafeon (Grass), Glaceon (Ice), and Sylveon (Fairy).  Hint 5 means that there are other "-eon" Pokemon that are not the 8 evolved ones, such as Charmeleon (7+ reptile) and Finneon (4+ fish).
>
>  Note that I have never played Pokemon so all of this is coming from my researching it just now.  There may be more going on here that I don't know about.

Comment: Yes, you got the main mechanism and the correct final phrase! As for the clue you haven’t gotten yet, rot13(gur zvffvyrf ner onfrq va gur HF). Good job!

Comment: @JS1 - A [Qat query](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=...t.eon&ent=Search&dict=6) will brute force resolve the [missiles group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raytheon_Missile_Systems)...